# Difficulty dual-booting Ubuntu and Windows 10 with UEFI

Tags: dual-boot, usb, uefi

I've been messing around all day trying do dual-boot Ubuntu 15.04 64-bit on my Dell XPS 12-9Q33 running Windows 10. I'm running into roadblocks everywhere however, so I thought I'd see if anyone with knowledge about these sorts of things had any advice for me!

Anyway, here are the steps I've taken so far:

- Shrunk my Windows partition
- Created a bootable USB with Ubuntu 15.04 64bit using the [Universal USB Installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/).
- Disabled hibernation entirely, presumably disabling Fast Boot.
- Disabled Secure Boot
- Tried with 2 different USB sticks, in both USB ports

No matter what I try, I just can't get my computer to recognize that there is a bootable USB available! This is in UEFI mode, of course - switching to legacy mode immediately lets the computer recognize the bootable USB, but will presumably create problems with the bootloader.

The only two boot options available in the setup/BIOS are 'Windows [something or other, I forget exactly]' and 'UEFI OS'. Selecting either of those options boots to Windows.

So, any ideas? Thanks so much for your time!

Daniel

Comment: /UEFI, /legacy, Ubuntu supports legacy even better than UEFI, it has both UEFI and BIOS mode, UEFI and BIOS bootloaders.

Comment: It sounds almost like you didn't make an EFI bootable USB. What are you using to make the USB sticks?

Comment: Many UEFI systems require a separate setting to allow USB (or any other device) boot. See if you have that setting somewhere. Often best to have secure boot off, but UEFI on, and CSM/BIOS/Legacy mode off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Ubuntu installation media seems to be improperly configured regarding the bootability.

When you have an already existing Ubuntu installation - recreate your installation media by:

1. Open built-in **Disks** tool – click the menu (right top corner) -  select **Restore Disk Image**.
2. Choose the Ubuntu iso image - select the USB drive to write it to and start the process.

In case you have to do it from within Windows - open **command prompt as administrator**.

1. Create your Ubuntu USB installation media by executing the following commands:

   ```
   diskpart  
   list disk  
   select disk ¹  
   clean  
   create partition primary  
   active  
   format fs=fat32 quick  
   assign letter=²  
   exit
   ```
2. Mount the Ubuntu iso file and copy the content to the USB drive.

Notes:
¹ = select the USB drive 
² = choose a free drive letter

Comment: Thank you! It appears that Universal USB Installer does NOT create a UEFI compatible bootable image. Using 'rufus' instead worked perfectly.